# UILocalNotification iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, uilocalnotification

I want to make a UILocalNotification in iOS8 that will run after the application is installed, and keep on running with the interval that was set when i ran the application.

Supposed a notification has a firedate of 10 seconds. So after i run the application, the notification will keep on coming after 10 seconds.

Here's the tricky part - 
I want the Notification to come irrespective of the application is in background or even terminated, the notification will keep on coming after 10 seconds, UNLESS i uninstall the application.

Is this feasible? i have completed the part where the Notification comes when the application is in background.I cannot make it run repeatedly though. But is it possible to make it as i stated above?

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past versions of iOS8 is not possible and I'm pretty sure also in the last one.
It exists a property called `repeatInterval` but it must be set in `NSCalendarUnit`: seconds, minutes, days, but there is no option for 10 seconds.
What it can't be absolutely done is uninstall the application by any means, except for user decision.
When you schedule a local notification this can be displayed also when your app is a suspended state.

Comment: So is it possible that once i run the application and the notification is set to fire in say 1 hour, it will do so, untill i uninstall the application from device OR simulator?

Comment: If you set repetition interval to 1 hour, each hour a local notification will be fired, but it will behave   if your app is in a suspended state killed or foreground

Comment: wil the notification still fire if the app is terminated?

Comment: yes, but you can't do any sort of processing until the user interact with the notification opening the app

Comment: can u provide me with a tutorial link or sort? as all i am getting is ios8 prior, and also i am recieving the interval as seconds, so i have to convert it into nscalender before changing the firedate right? and still in doubt as to how to implement the repeatinterval

Comment: You can't convert NSCalendar you can just choose one of them: second, minute, hour, day etc. The meaning is that you can trigger a local notifcation for repetition each sec, or each min, or each hour. http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/ . the other way is schedule a local notitication each 10 sec but you can't schedule more than 64 notifications.

Answer (score 0):

**UILocalNotification** has a property : `@property(nonatomic) NSCalendarUnit repeatInterval`